# Why is my anchored link not going to the right place?

Tags: css, html, position

My nav bar correctly links to my 'work' section, but if I click ABOUT on the nav bar, it drops down to about 300px above the 'about' h2.  I feel it may have to do with positions, displays? I can get the ABOUT anchored link to correctly go to the about section if I add

```
#about{
    margin-top: 360px
}
```

Although this appears to be a poor patch on a larger problem with my construction. I've tried doing a lot of different things but I keep ending up with my work, about, and contact section starting to overlap into each other which I can't understand either.  The divs dont seem to be stacking properly or something.  ANY help is greatly appreciated.

http://wrobbins.me is the site. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `position:relative`?

Comment: Well, my 'top' div is position: fixed, and after that is a mainwrap that contains the sections: main, work, about, contact.  mainwrap is set to relative and then top: 43px; so it doesnt run into the 43px high top div.  After that, I'd like all sections to just fall into place and I'm confused why they don't.  I've tried adding position: relative to a number of divs and havent had good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link takes you exactly to where the `about` element is, it's just that the text in the element is pushed down by the `job` elements in the block above.

The problem is the `jobwrap` element. The floating elements inside it doesn't affect its size, so it has the height zero.

Add `overflow:hidden` to the `#jobwrap` style, and it will contain its children, and the `about` element will start below it.

Comment: `#jobwrap {overflow:hidden;}` will cut shadows on the right side. This can be fixed with another clearfix method (like [this](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)) or by making #jobwrap block few pixels wider.

Answer (score 0):

When you use floats you should "clear" its parent or block you want to be below. Now your #jobwrap block have zero height and there is the problem with #about position. Use `#about{cloar:both;}` as hotfix and read more about floats and clearfix.